# If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ are distinct, then there are infinitely many $n$ such that $a+n$, $b+n$ and $c+n$ are relatively prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, chinese-remainder-theorem

> If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ are distinct, then there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a+n$, $b+n$ and $c+n$ are pairwise relatively prime.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Here's what I did so far:

We note first that
$$\begin{cases} \operatorname{gcd}(x+a, x+b) = \operatorname{gcd}(a-b, x+b)\\
                \operatorname{gcd}(x+b, x+c) = \operatorname{gcd}(b-c, x+c)\\
                \operatorname{gcd}(x+a, x+c) = \operatorname{gcd}(c-a, x+a)
\end{cases}.$$
Let $a-b = p_1^{n_1}\ldots p_k^{n_k}$, $b-c = q_1^{m_1}\ldots q_s^{m_s}$ and $c-a = r_1^{l_1} \ldots r_t^{l_t}$ be the prime factorization of each difference. We can now set up the following system of congruences:
$$\begin{cases} x+b \equiv 1 \mod p_j, j = 1, \ldots, k\\
                x+a \equiv 1 \mod r_j, j = 1, \ldots, t\\
                x+c \equiv 1 \mod q_j, j = 1, \ldots, s
\end{cases}.$$
A solution to the system above would imply that $x+a$, $x+b$ and $x+c$ are pairwise relatively prime. Indeed, given that $x+b$ is not divisible by any prime in the prime factorization of $a-b$, we must have $\operatorname{gcd}(x+a, x+b) = 1$ by the initial observation. This argument also holds for the other sums. The only issue with the system above is that we may have indices $i, j$ such that $p_i = r_j$, for example, since they belong to a different prime factorization. Here, however, I thought about using the Generalized Chinese Remainder Theorem. It seems to be applicable because, for instance, if $p_i = r_j$, then $\operatorname{gcd}(p_i, r_j) = p_i = r_j$. Also, $(1-b) - (1-a) = a-b$, which means $\operatorname{gcd}(p_i, r_j)$ divides $(1-b) - (1-a)$. Since there is a solution by the GCRT, say $x_0$, there are infinitely many: $x = x_0 + n (p_1\ldots p_k q_1 \ldots q_s r_1 \ldots r_t), n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (of course, removing the duplicate primes in this product).

Does this work or am I missing something?

Please, don't close this question. I know this question has already been asked, but my attempt is significantly different from the others, so I'd like some feedback on what I did.

Comment: Per MSE: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so.

Comment: The easiest (trivial!) way to do problems like this is to reduce it to the (trivial) Stieltjes  proof of infinitely many **co**primes (to $c)$ in arithmetic progression, yielding a few-line proof as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4536013/242) in the linked dupe.